# Customize UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ipad, background, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm new to `Objective-C` and I'm trying to remove the background of a `UISearchBar` to use my one image for the `textfield`, but once I remove it, it shows a `UISegmentedControl`  in the background.

```
for (UIView *subview in [projectSearch subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")]) {
            [(UITextField *)subview setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pg-14-search-field.png"]];
        }
    }
```

How can I prevent `UISegmentedControl` from appearing after I remove the `UISearchBar` background?

Comment: this code works fine for me. I hope this image name u r giving is correct. please see if there is any other info (maybe a screenshot) that u can give to explain it better...

Comment: Where is it that you are adding the code, under viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in self.searchBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")])
        {

        }
    }
}
```